# Assigning a password to a word doc using Read-host using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, passwords

I have the following script to update passwords with an autogenerated 32 character password. It then makes a password-protected Word doc so that we can update our secure password library. Generating the password works fine.

The problem occurs when I try to assign a password to the password-protected word doc. I can hard code a string directly such as:

`$PL_Document.Password =  'blah'`

In the case where I hard code it everything works fine. I get a password protected word doc with the login info.

However, when I try to read it in using Read-host then assign it, the script hangs.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

cls

#************ Create Document ******************************

function CreateDocument 
{

$PL_Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

#$PL_Word.Visible = $true

$PL_Document = $PL_Word.Documents.Add()

$PL_Report = 'C:\TEMP\MyDoc.docx'

$PL_Document.SaveAs([ref]$PL_Report,[ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocument)

$PL_Selection = $PL_Word.Selection

#****************** Password Protect the Word File ********

$PL_PwdEntry = Read-Host ("Enter the password for the text document record") -AsSecureString

$PL_WdPWD = ConvertFrom-SecureString $PL_PwdEntry

$PL_Document.Password =  $PL_WdPWD


#************** Write Password to Document *************************************


$PL_Selection.TypeParagraph()

$PL_Selection.TypeText("Username: $PL_UN")

$PL_Selection.TypeParagraph()

$PL_Selection.TypeText("Password: $PL_PWD")

#************** Close Document *************************************

$PL_Document.Close()

$PL_Word.Quit()
}

#****************** Create Password ************************

$PL_PWD = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(32,3)

Write-Host "`n`n"

$PL_UN = "Prime\"+(Read-Host ("Enter the username. Entering the Primelending domain is not neccessary."))

Write-Host "`nSummary of the change" -f Yellow

Write-Host "============================" -f Yellow

Write-Host "`nUsername: " -NoNewline

Write-Host "$PL_UN" -f Yellow

Write-Host "New Password: " -NoNewline

Write-Host "$PL_PWD`n" -f Yellow

Write-Host "Do you want to update AD (Y/N)" -NoNewline -f Yellow

$PL_Query = Read-Host (" ")


If ($PL_Query.ToUpper() -eq "Y") {
  
  Write-Host "`nMaking change" -f Green
  
  #Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $PL_UN -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "$PL_PWD" -Force)
  
  CreateDocument
}
  
else {Write-Host "`nAbandoning change" -f Green }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$PL_WdPWD = ConvertFrom-SecureString $PL_PwdEntry` part of your script will not be returning a plain text password and instead will be an encoded version of the password that will have a much longer length than that of the original password.

From what I recall Word has a password limit of 255 characters, which this value would likely exceed and is probably the cause of the hang as Word cannot handle it.

If you're using PowerShell v7 or above change `$PL_WdPWD = ConvertFrom-SecureString $PL_PwdEntry` to `$PL_WdPWD = ConvertFrom-SecureString $PL_PwdEntry -AsPlainText` in order to get the plain text version of the password

Alternatively, seeing as you're needing the plain text password straight away and trying to store it in a separate variable, just get the ***Read-Host*** cmdlet to return you a plain text password instead by changing:

```
$PL_PwdEntry = Read-Host ("Enter the password for the text document record") -AsSecureString
$PL_WdPWD = ConvertFrom-SecureString $PL_PwdEntry
```

to

```
$PL_WdPWD = Read-Host ("Enter the password for the text document record")
```

**Edit following comments**

It appears that Word hangs when passing the `$PL_WdPWD` variable to `$PL_Document.Password` is due to a lack of quotes.

In order to resolve this, you can change this line

`$PL_Document.Password =  $PL_WdPWD`

to this

`$PL_Document.Password =  "$PL_WdPWD"`

**Note:** in your updated code, you're still using `Read-Host -AsSecureString` and then converting it with `ConvertFrom-SecureString`. This will not be giving you the password you expect and instead return an encoded version of that password. See my original answer for details on this.

Comment: Thanks! However, now I have a different problem. I made the change to read it in as a plain text string. Now when I enter the password for the file, the cursor moves to the next line, but the script doesn't continue. I just have a blinking cursor.

Comment: I can also see that it has opened word doc for editing in the C:\TEMP folder. It seems like something is hanging. Whether that is the script, Word, or PS ISE I can't tell.

Comment: Hi @StevenBeckmann. I've updated my answer to reflect your updated code